# Spring Mongo Aggregate query to fetch distinct country name and country code from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I have a collection named Location which has couple of attributes of which I want to fetch only distinct country code and country name.

Below query works fine in Mongo DB.

```
db.location.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": { countryCode: "$countryCode", countryName: "$countryName" }}}]);
```

I want to convert same query into SpringMongoReactiveAggretate Query. Below code has some issues. Please help me figure frame the correct code.

```
@Repository
public class AggregateQueryRepository {
    
    @Autowired
    ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;
    
    public Flux<Location> getAllCountryCodeAndCountry(String countryCode, String countryName) {
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("_id").is(countryCode).and(countryName)),
                group("_id").push("location").as("location")
        );
        Flux<Location> output
                = reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "location", Location.class);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `match` stage and you should pass the field names to `group` as parameter:

```java
    public Flux<Location> getAllCountryCodeAndCountry() {
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                group("countryCode", "countryName")
        );
        return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "location", Location.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution works. I want to further understand how will I map the query result to appropriate fields of my Location object.
Currently the response I got from query looks like below     
{
        "_id": "{\"countryCode\": \"IN\", \"countryName\": \"India\"}"
 }
My Location object has _id, countryCode and countryName attributes but this query response has mapped everything to _id field but I want to map the countryCode to my Location object countryCode and countryName to my Location object countryName. If you could help me with the same.